# C# adding string to image, using the max font size

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I want to add 2 string to an image as follows:

```
This is Text
------------
------------
------------
--Other-----
```

How do I use the largest font size possible without have the String go off the side of the image?

example: if text is too big then it goes off the image::

```
This is Text That is too big
------------
------------
------------
--Other-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this script on my previous projects to fit some text into the image by calculating its  dimensions for each font-size. when the font size is bigger than the image's width, it lowers the font size by 0.1em and tries again until the text fits in the image. Here's the code :

```
public static string drawTextOnMarker(string markerfile, string text, string newfilename,Color textColor)
    {
        //Uri uri = new Uri(markerfile, UriKind.Relative);
        //markerfile = uri.AbsolutePath;
        //uri = new Uri(newfilename, UriKind.Relative);
        //newfilename = uri.AbsolutePath;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(newfilename)))
        {
            try
            {

                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(markerfile));
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
                StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat();
                strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);
                float fontsize = 10;
                bool sizeSetupCompleted = false;
                while (!sizeSetupCompleted)
                {                        
                    SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(text, new Font("Verdana", fontsize, FontStyle.Bold));
                    if (mySize.Width > 24 || mySize.Height > 13)
                    {
                        fontsize-= float.Parse("0.1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sizeSetupCompleted = true;
                    }
                }

                g.DrawString(text, new Font("Verdana", fontsize, FontStyle.Bold), myBrush, new RectangleF(4, 3, 24, 8), strFormat);
                bmp.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(newfilename));
                return newfilename.Substring(2);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return markerfile.Substring(2);
            }
        }
        return newfilename.Substring(2);
    }
```

Comment: `fontsize-= float.Parse("0.1");`, why not just do `fontsize -= 1.0f`?

Comment: because I was learning C# and that was my first month. :) They do the same at the end. For example I was using String mystring = ""; and my friend was using String mystring = String.Empty(); and when I ask why do you do like this, he said that he was used to it. Different methods, same results.

Comment: and BTW, the mysize.width > 24 || mysize.height > 13 defines the size of the image which is hardcoded there. you should change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Note that this is an ASP question. It's worth to mention that you need a reference to Windows.Forms.Drawing, plus that it's in general not recommended practice to include it in ASP projects.

Comment: The title says C#, sorry. And the reference is System.Drawing. It is worth using in web applications such as ASP.net. I know it because I use it like I use GD in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
    float width = g.MeasureString(text, font).Width;
    float scale = bmp.Width / width;
    g.ScaleTransform(scale, scale); //Simple trick not to use other Font instance
    g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty);
    g.ResetTransform();
    ...
}
```

Your text won't be always 100% width if you use `TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit` or similar, but I think that's not a problem as you just want to make sure the text alawys fits in the image.